# Is there a way to view the query or last history in a BigQuery Table?

Tags: google-bigquery

A coworker created a table in BigQuery using "create or replace table" function. Unfortunately the query wasn't documented. I was wondering if there's a way to see the underlying query behind the table or a way to access the edit history of the table?

Comment: your use case is not too clear to go with more help - the only what I can add more to what already there  - check if [Work with change history](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-history) will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use below as an example

```
select ddl
from `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` 
where table_name = 'us_county_area'
```

with out put like below

[image]

There are quite a number of very usefull INFORMATION SCHEMA Views to use

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried it but it didn't show the whole thing

Comment: The table is a partition table, so with the query you provided, it didn't show anything within the select statement

Comment: what do you mean by "whole thing"?

Comment: look into other INFORMATION SCHEMA views - that is exactly why I mentioned them in my answer :o)

Comment: In the table, there should be around 800 lines. With the ddl function, it only shows me around 100. It doesn't show me the codes after OPTIONS. The rest of the 700 lines should be within a select statement. The ddl function doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find this query in INFORMATION SCHEMA JOBS:

```
SELECT * FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT 
WHERE 
  job_type = 'QUERY' and 
  statement_type = 'CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT' and 
  lower(query) LIKE '%create%table%foo%'  -- replace foo with your table name
```